# MinGW error: No such file or directory exists

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw

I'm running MinGW on windows XP SP3. I wrote a simple program in C++ and saved it as a .cpp file. When I tried to compile it in MinGW at the correct directory a message appeared saying 
" Error: No such file or directory exists" but I know its in the correct directory.

This is what I typed into MinGW

```
cd C:\MinGW test  # Where I saved the .cpp file
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe
```

After that an error appears.

Also I did change the  Environment Settings path to C:\MinGW\bin

Comment: `a message appeared saying " Error: No such file or directory exists" but I know its in the correct directory.` These two statements are contradictory. Your computer is not lying to you. Check again.

Comment: Question appears to be a basic question about using the DOS-like command prompt in Windows.

Comment: use the `dir` command to list files in a directory to make sure it is there

Comment: Also you should have copied more of the console output to help others understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it to work, you should run the compiler from the folder where the program is, not where MinGW is. First, you need to set your PATH to include MinGW. You can do this with `set PATH = C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%` on the command line.

Then, `cd` to where the program is located and run `g++ test.cpp -o test.exe` to compile, and `test` to run.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't work. I entered "set PATH = C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%" on the command line and it responds with "sh: fg: %PATH%: no such job" and then I tried to compile the program but the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

`cd C:\MinGW test` does not look right.

Did you mean `cd C:\MinGW\test\`?

Also remember that you have to separately change into the `C:` drive before performing `cd`. What does your prompt say? It'll tell you what directory you're in.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is complaining that the mingw compiler (g++) is not in the path.

Add it to your path by going to Control Panel-> System-> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Look for the PATH variable and edit it. At the end add a semicolon separater and then the correct path to the MingW bin folder. Then close, then reopen your command prompt. If you now type g++ by itself it should complain that you have no input files. Then use the command you tried previously.

Comment: Thanks but still didn't work.

Comment: What does it say when you type g++? What path did you use for MingW?