# g++: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mingw

System:
g++ version: g++ (TDM-2 mingw32) 4.4.1
windows 7 32 bit 
Env path: `C:\Python33\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\bin;C:\Dwimperl\c\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Cygwin\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;`

Error:

```
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin>g++ -o first.exe D:\first.cpp
g++: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

I took look on similar questions on SO, but none of them have answers for me.
Per one suggestion, I added Mingw, path to env variable path, as seen above.

**Update:** First I never believed this, but this worked for me.
[MinGW error: No such file or directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330383/mingw-error-no-such-file-or-directory-exists?rq=1)

Comment: Provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct  Example](http://sscce.org)! BTW, if you want to call [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you need to `#include <windows.h>`, not `#include <CreateProcess>`.

Comment: Forgive me, but what should I do with this question, because i found solution to this on SO only. It was my mistake/ignorance, that I didn't try one of the method suggested as solution.

Comment: @Oswald It's not the OP that want's to call `CreateProcess()` but g++ as far I can see. GCC's missing header file error message looks quite different!

Answer (score 1):

This error is most likely caused by a problem with PATH. I suspect that in your case `g++` tries to run some utility in PATH, but fails, because of error in PATH, or because wrong `g++` is executed with given parameters. For example, you might have some tool in `C:\Cygwin\bin`.

If that helps anybody, my case for the error was invalid slash in PATH, which was set as:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"E:\godot.src\.locally/mingw32\bin"
```

Replacing the last entry in `PATH` with the stuff below fixed that:

```
E:\godot.src\.locally\mingw32\bin
```