# mingw32-make : no such file or directory

Tags: mingw

I have installed mingw32-make from MinGW Installer. However when I run it on command prompt, I get the following response:

```
mingw32-make: *** INTERNAL: readdir: No such file or directory
.  Stop.
```

I don't know why this error shows up. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330383/mingw-error-no-such-file-or-directory-exists

Comment: @nevilad I have checked this link and I have already set path variable. MinGW does not show any problem when I compile a simple cpp program. The problem is specifically with mingw32-make.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I have the exact same problem. One thing to add is that if I execute `mingw32-make.exe --version` or even `mingw32-make.exe -h` it works perfectly fine. It is just executing `mingw32-make.exe`  that shows this problem. This is very weird.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that it's having problems listing directory contents.

Maybe you should check the `Makefile` to see if it's referring to a path that doesn't exist.
Or maybe it has to do with Linux/Windows path notations (slashes versus backslashes and drive letter).